# How to use online build CKEditor in angular?

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I want to embed the ckeditor into a Material Tabs.
I want to the editor support font color feature, 
so I build the ckeditor online from the following link:

https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/

And then install the CKEditor 5 WYSIWYG editor component for Angular by the following command:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular
```

According to the instruction in the below [web page](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#using-a-custom-ckeditor-5-build), I copy the ckeditor.js and corresponding translation files to the src directory and import it to the component file; and then modify the tsconfig.json.

However, the editor does not show.

how can I configure the editor so that it can support font color feature?

Here is the [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oqxucs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 1):

According to [ckeditor5 document](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html) You need to follow this steps:-

1. You need to install `npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular` && `npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic` as CKeditor dependancy.
2. Import CKeditor Module `import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';` in main app module. && add `CKEditorModule` in `imports`.

   @NgModule({
     imports: [
       CKEditorModule
     ]
   })
3. Add dependency in app.component like `import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';`
4. add in  `public Editor = ClassicEditor;` in app component like this.

   export class AppComponent {
     public Editor = ClassicEditor;
   }
5. add in `.html` file like  `<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>`

Hope this helps you :-)

Working example [CKEditor example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyyd74)

Comment: I follow your instruction to make ckeditor show in stackblitz environment. However, how to configure the editor so that it can support font color feature?

Comment: Okay, for that you need to follow the CKEditor official documentation.https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html

Comment: These aren't the instruction for integrating with online builder

Comment: @DhairyTripathi, These is not instruction / solution, then please provide solution. I'll be more happy if you provide solutions. thanks. brother for you input :-)